# Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two (Int) operands

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I am getting a `Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two (Int) operands` error when I put the following code in a Swift playground in Xcode.

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
sumOf()
sumOf(42, 597, 12)
```

The above was a function calculating the total sum of any numbers.
Below is a function calculating the average of the numbers. The function is calling the `sumOf()` function from within itself.

```
func avg(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var avg:Float = ( sumOf(numbers) ) / ( numbers.count ) //Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two (Int) operands
    return avg
}

avg(1, 2, 3);
```

*Note: I have looked everywhere in stack exchange for the answer, but the questions all are different from mine because mine is involving two `Int`s, the same type and not different two different types.*

I would  like it if someone could help me to solve the problem which I have.

Comment: For others who get to this question from Google whose situations don't involve the "lists of numbers" issue, see also the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557214/swift-operator-throwing-error-on-two-ints). Essentially, if A is already declared as a Double of CGFloat or whatever, and B and C are integers, A = B / C will fail with this error message, which obscures the real issue and solution: A = Double(B/C).

Answer (score 1):

Despite the error message it seems that you cannot forward the sequence (...) operator. A single call of `sumOf(numbers)` within the `agv()` function gives an error `cannot invoke sumOf with an argument of type ((Int))`

Answer (score -3):

The error is telling you what to do.  If you refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_operators.html

```
/  Division.
A binary arithmetic operator that divides the number to its left by the number to its right.
Class of operands: integer, real
Class of result: real
```

The second argument has to be real.  Convert it  like so.  I don't use xcode, but I think my syntax is correct.

```
var avg:Float = ( sumOf(numbers) ) / Float( numbers.count )
```

Comment: dividing two integers is perfectly fine in Swift. It returns the integer quotient without the remainder. It's not AppleScript ;-)

Comment: @vadian  Ok, please enlighten me.  Why is the error saying it wont work with two integers ?  And why is the documentation saying the same thing ?

Comment: The documentation quote is from the AppleScript documentation, different language - different rules. The error message says `.. two (Int) operands` - Int with parentheses is not the same as Int

Comment: As declared above, I dont know much about it.  I guess a lot of people are wrong about Swift then.  [Heres the duplicate of this ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181082/why-cant-i-divide-integers-in-swift)