# Swift 3 error: "Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'int' operands"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I know that there is a question with the same title but I think it is a different problem because I cannot solve it with the solutions provided. The question related is: [Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two (Int) operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132491/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-int-operands). I also have looked at the question that is supposed to be the original.

But I got this error only trying to use a variable inside `UIColor` function:

**Work**

```
UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 24/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
```

**Does not work**

```
var colorRGB = 74
UIColor(red: colorRGB/255, green: 24/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
```

So I cannot understand why my error happens. It throws me the following error:

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'int' operands

I thought that it would be the same because is just the same value in both cases but I am getting that error instead. I think that in the first example there are also two ints values and it does not throw that error.

What can I do to use a variable inside my function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: colorRGB must be of CGFloat type

Comment: var colorRGB: CGFloat = 74

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UIColor` constructor takes four `CGFloat` parameters.

```
UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 24/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
```

compiles because `CGFloat` conforms to the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`
protocol. From the context the compiler tries to make
`74/255` a `CGFloat`, and interprets all the numbers as `CGFloat`
literals, and `/` as the `CGFloat` division operator.

That does not work with

```
var colorRGB = 74
UIColor(red: colorRGB/255, green: 24/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
```

There is no context for the `74` literal, so that it is taken
as an `Int` by default. But there is no
suitable division operator to make `colorRGB/255` a `CGFloat`.

You have to define the variable explicitly with the correct type:

```
var colorRGB: CGFloat = 74
UIColor(red: colorRGB/255, green: 24/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
```

---

*Remark:* This would also compile:

```
var colorRGB = 74
UIColor(red: CGFloat(colorRGB/255), green: 24/255, blue: 141/255, alpha: 1)
```

But then `colorRGB/255` becomes the *integer division* and evaluates
to zero, compare [Strange Swift numbers type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813516/strange-swift-numbers-type-casting).

Comment: Wow! Nice explanation! Thank you very much! I will accept the answer as fast I could (I need at least 10 min to do it)