# Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Tags: swift

I am getting error like Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double' - using Swift. Anyone help me to fix

```
var amountPaid: Int = 0

func decimalNumber() -> NSNumber? {
        return amountPaid == 0 ? 0 : amountPaid / 100.0
    }
```

Comment: You need to make sure that both types for which the operator is applied are the same. In your case you need to basically cast amountPaid as such Double(amountPaid) / 100.00.

Comment: Please, do not use `NSNumber` in Swift. Please, don't declare methods as returning optionals when they cannot really return `nil`.

Comment: Added answer with both the conditions

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your code. Firstly, `amountPaid` is an `Int` (no decimal places) while `100.0` is a `Double` (with decimal places). To divide them, they have to be of the same type. Secondly, your function needs to return `NSNumber?` but you are not doing so. Use this code:

```
var amountPaid: Int = 0

func decimalNumber() -> NSNumber? {
    return amountPaid == 0 ? 0 : Double(amountPaid) / 100.0 as NSNumber
}
```

Using `Double(amountPaid)` will convert `amountPaid` to `Double` for dividing with `100.0` and `as NSNumber` will return the correct type.

Also, `amountPaid ==` is unnecessary as `0.0 / 100.0` is `0` anyways.

Comment: It should be also said that the `amountPaid == 0` check is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks... It is working fine.

Comment: @Sulthan Edited to include it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are possible two ways for you:

**First Int to Double:**

```
Double(yourIntValue)
```

Use like

```
var amountPaid: Int = 0

func decimalNumber() -> NSNumber? {
    return amountPaid == 0 ? 0 : Double(amountPaid) / 100.0
}
```

**Second option:**

**Double to Int**

```
Int(yourDoubleValue)
```

Use like

```
var amountPaid: Int = 0

    func decimalNumber() -> NSNumber? {
            return amountPaid == 0 ? 0 : amountPaid / Int(100.0)
        }
```

Use it any way you like:

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181082/why-cant-i-divide-integers-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

> Conversions between integer and floating-point numeric types must be made explicit

You are trying to divide an `int` by a `double` and thereby implicitly converting from int to double. Either change the division to `100` instead of `100.0` or change the data type of `amountPaid` to `double`.