# How To Convert Car km/miles in to km by Year?

Tags: swift

everybody.

I got logic problem with car odometer, i don't understand how to devide a car age in km by year.

For example i got car with 2015 year and 250 000 km in odometer.

it's ok, if i just minus current year with registration year i got car age then i just deviding a car age in odometer or odo in age depending on numbers. then i got a car km route by year.
but what if i want get age of car with 1920 year and 1 km of full route. or car with last year.

it does not show me a current data, in example below

```
    func getOdoByYear(registration: Int, currentYear: Int, currentODO: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        if  currentODO == 0 || currentYear == registration {
        
            return currentODO
        }
        
        var carAge = currentYear - registration
        
        if carAge >= currentODO {
            return carAge /  currentODO
        } else {
            return currentODO / carAge
        }
    }
```

if car registered year before i got a one year of age of car,
and if a car route is only 1 km it also cant be calculated from 1920 for example.

Comment: Do not use inappropriate tags.

Comment: ok, understand.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Would you please provide an example with input data and the expected output? Why are you comparing `carAge` (years) with `currentODO` (km) ?

Comment: So My car first registration is 1920 year and current year is 2024. i'm first calculation age of car. this is 104 years. for example car route of all times is 1 km or 7 km. odo show 7km. my basic logic shows me that car have 14km every year. how i get how much car route all this 104 years. yes i understand its not truly but its show me wrong km by year

Comment: There is no simple way to calculate the age of a car based on the odometer reading. I have had a car that travelled more than 150,000 miles in 3 years. i now have a car that has travelled less than 100,000 in 18 years.

Comment: @jcmaxuser if the car is 104 years old and the ODO shows 7 km, why do you say it drove for 14 km every year? It should be ~ 67.31 m every year (as average of course).

Comment: how to calculate it, because logic that i got it show me a 14

Comment: @jcmaxuser 7 km / 104 years

Comment: how old are you? If less than 10, I could understand, but really dude?

Comment: If I read the question correctly this is about integer division and always getting zero returned for edge cases. The solution OP should use is most likely to work with Double or some other floating point type, both when doing the calculations and for the return value.

Comment: See these two questions for more information on integer division, [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181082/why-cant-i-divide-integers-in-swift) and [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383062/math-divison-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the average of kilometers traveled in a year by a car, you should just divide the km traveled by the age of the car.

Example, given:

- current year: 2024
- year of registration: 1920
- total km traveled (ODO): 7 km

the average of km traveled in a year is calculated by:

```
7 km / (2024 - 1920) ~ 67.31 m/year
```

Code example:

```
func getOdoByYear(registration: Int, currentYear: Int, currentODO: Int) -> Double {
    // TODO: check parameters, i.e. currentYear > registration, currentODO >= 0
    var carAge = currentYear - registration
    var average:Double = Double(currentODO) / Double(carAge)
    return average
}
```

you also should handle the case `registration == currentYear`, otherwise you get a division by zero. This is up to you: you can just return the `currentODO` (even the first year is not completed yet) or throw an error because it might not make sense at all.